# clone and push to remote server repository

Tags: git, openssh

I have a remote server with a git repository ready to be cloned... The problem is that I need to access that server using ssh with a key file authentication that i have saved on my local machine...

I've created an empty local folder and I make:

```
git clone ssh://username@45.645.465.12:/path_to_my_rep/.git
```

But, of course, I am getting a permission denied error.. How can I say to git where to pick my ssh key file???

I have tried creating a conf file on ~/.ssh/conf and adding this lines:

```
Host 45.645.465.12
    Hostname 45.645.465.12
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/myKeyFile.pem
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Cloning into 'gestioner'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: did you generate ssh key and uploaded to server?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068298/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository-please-make-sure-you-have-th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my conf file under  ~/.ssh/ and it looks like this:

```
Host myhost
    User myUser
    IdentityFile /path_to_my_key_file
```

My main mistake was that i was running git clone as root and because of that openSSH was not reading my conf file under home/user/ but under /root/...

After correcting this 2 things git clone worked just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've already generated a key-pair, you need to provide your public key to git server admin so that it gets added to authorized keys list. The key should be appended to `authorized_keys` file inside `.ssh/` dir.