# Need to clone a GIT repository into remote server

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-repo

I Need to clone a GIT repository into remote server via SSH. I have tried doing this in the traditional way, using

```
git clone git@github.xyz.com:username/repository.git
```

The above gave me

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

1)Repo exists, I created the repo for test purpose
2)it's a public repo.

Comment: If it's a public repo why hide its URL?

Comment: Sounds like you might need to add an SSH key to https://github.com/settings/ssh

Comment: Most likely it sounds like a SSH keys issue. Just in case, be sure you can reach github from your remote server. Here they managed to solve something pretty similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068298/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository-please-make-sure-you-have-th/40049051

Answer (score 1):

First, if it is a public repository, you should be able to clone it through https URL

```
git clone https://github.xyz.com/username/repository.git
```

Second, to know more about why your SSH URL fails, set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v`.
Then clone again, and check the error messages.

A `ssh -Tv git@github.xyz.com` should print your name. If not, as commented, you need to register your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` public SSH key to your profile on `github.xyz.com`.