# Github: How can I push to an organization's repo that I don't have permissions to clone

Tags: git, github

I have two github accounts. I have created SSH keys for both, and configured them accordingly. I know that my config works because I can push to both accounts for my personal repos fine.
Example config

```
Host github.com
etc
IdentityFile: id_rsa

Host github-second
etc
IdentityFile: id_rsa_second
```

To add remote for my normal account, I use
`git remote add origin git@github.com:account/repo.git`
To add remote for the second account, I use
`git remote add origin git@github-second:second-account/other-repo.git`

I am now a member of an organization with my second account.
The url for the repo of interest looks like `github.com/organization/org-repo` vs `github.com/second-account/org-repo`.
I have tried to add the org repo using:
`git remote add origin git@github-second:organization/org-repo`
and I indeed got the repo files on my local machine. However, I cannot push to the org repo.
Error:

````
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.```

I have contacted the organization and they said that I have full write access. 
I am not sure what else to try.
````

Comment: Try `git remote add origin git@github.com:second-account/other-repo.git` instead, if your repos are all on github.

Comment: @Niloct I tried that too. But for a sanity check, I tried again. And I get the same error. I have also tried: `git remote add origin git@github:second-account/organization/org-repo.git` to no avail.

Comment: `git@github-second:` doesn't make sense, `github-second` is the domain that hosts the git repository and your question points it should be `github.com`.

Comment: @Niloct my understanding is that different github accounts should have different hosts in the config, but hostname can be the same (github.com). The id_rsa should be different. Since the organization permissions are on the second account, I think that when I use ```git@github.com```, I am pointing to the first account, which does not have permissions for the organization.

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068298/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository-please-make-sure-you-have-th

Comment: @Sandra Start debugging with `ssh -Tv git@github-second` . Add the output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by:

1. Re-adding the id_rsa_second
2. Check `ssh -T git@github-second` and make sure it is pointed to `second-account`
3. `git remote add origin git@github-second:second-account/org-repo.git`
4. `git remote add upstream git@github-second:org-account/org-repo.git`
5. Push to upstream.
   Hopefully, this helps someone else.

Comment: Nice to see that. Congratulations :)